# Magento replace ORM call with SQL

Tags: mysql, magento

I am trying to figure out the table structure to replace the following with an SQL query. I can't quite wrap my head around this just yet.

`$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

return $product->getAttributeText('Color');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to figure out table structure and build your query in SQL again.

Just enable `$_debug` and `$_logAllQueries` in the file `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and the next time you refresh any particular page, you could see every query that is ran in Magento in `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log` file.